# How to collect click and page view statistics from webpart in SP2010

Tags: 2010

I have created a SPA within a content editor. I now need to track clicks and page views statistics. The site cannot use any 3. Party tools, so it needs to stay within this SP solution. 
I'm thinking this can be done with lists, but has anyone done something like this before? I'm looking for list setup and approaches. :)
Thanks in advance.

Extra info: there would properly be arround 10.000 people using this site.

Update:
Sorry for these missing information. 
I only have access to create webparts and manage list. So only frontend code. I cannot change masterpages, run server-side code or anything like that.

In my SPA, I have a number of elements(divs and span) that I eould like to track clicks on. 
It seems, that based on the answers its possible to use a statistics webpart to track all the page views. 
But how can I track clicks on my elements? My first thought was to use the REST API to update a list with the clicks, but since there will be around 10.000 users clickin on it. I need to have timestamp on each click. Having the username for click is only nice-2-have.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint 2010 you can use **Web Analytics web parts**. These will help you to get no. of page views, their graphical representations and many more anlaytics. And you can add this web part to your SPA.

This [MSDN Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ecm/2010/03/20/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010/) will help you to set up web analytics for SP2010

**Update**: As per your explanation

> My first thought was to use the REST API to update a list with the
>   clicks, but since there will be around 10.000 users clickin on it. I
>   need to have timestamp on each click. Having the username for click is
>   only nice-2-have

Doing all these stuffs all by yourself (custom) will lead to more & more complexity as "*How will you manage multiple clicks by user? happened on same date? how many HTML elements you will be tracking for SPA? storing all Users alongside their valid clicks?And you said 10,000+ users?....etc etc.*"

I suggest, it is better to you use web analytics feature of SP 2010. you can modify your analytics result sets easily.

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough information. Please see mu update on the question.

Comment: Ohhh. so clearly you can  not deploy and custom sandbox solution code. But you have to enable services on your environment for web analytics. you can ask your IT admin to do so.. Refernce: https://www.habaneroconsulting.com/insights/enabling-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010#.WUtuNGiGPIV

Comment: It will take more than a month :( but thanks! I will let them know :)

Comment: check my answer updates

Comment: I totally agree with you! But can I - with the access I got - use the web part analytics feature to track clicks on my divs and buttons?

Comment: Actually No, It will only track the number of views for a single item, page or document.. Kindly share your support by upvoting and marking as answers if It helped!

Comment: Web analytics is server side. It will track page refreshes from the server but is useless in a SPA context.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check these Links

http://hitcounter.codeplex.com/

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Create-Custom-hit-counter-d68d9e52

Also 
You can use inbuilt SharePoint 2010 web analytic feature,where you will get "Total Number of Page Views".

Go to site Action -> site settings and check for

Site Web Analytics reports

Site Collection Web Analytics reports

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough information. Please see mu update on the question.

Answer (score 1):

SPAs are complicated, and since all the action within a SPA takes place in the browser, you're going to have to implement a client side solution to meet the requirement. Server-side analytics are not going to do anything except track when your app is loaded from the server.

Lists are a bad option in my opinion because they don't scale well, and you're going to have hundreds of thousands, or perhaps millions, of entries in a short amount of time.

I've had success with [Azure Application Insights](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-azure-web-apps) on a project similar to yours. You can log trace messages on custom events and report on them in a lot of different ways.  I'd push back hard on the restriction on third party tools for this; it just makes zero sense to roll your own analytics solution. App Insights costs in the single digits of dollars per month on the project I implemented it for. You could spend weeks developing a solution that won't even begin to approach the same level of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Web analytics would do but in our farm due to performance issues we have turned it off. So in such cases, i used WebLog Expert tool, it reads all your IIS logs and gives you a consolidated report from which you can pick the views etc. For free version it gives you HTML report, for paid version it gives PDF report and few other additional features.